# Ruby: each_with_index bails when encountering Range as string, NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the new Postgresql feature of storing an array in my Rails 4 app. As you know, each element of an array stored in PG is in strings.

So my array = [7, 8..9, 10] is what you want but is stored in PG as {'7', '8..9', '10'}. I can test for each element to turn it back into an integer or Range as needed.

But I get a NoMethodError: undefined method 'each_with_index' for "8..9":String

```
 array.each_with_index do |item, index|
   puts "index=#{index}, item=#{item}"
 end
```

The portion of my schema.rb is below:

```
create_table "items", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "category"
  t.string   "sub_category"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "explanation"
  t.integer  "scoring"
  t.integer  "high_score"
  t.boolean  "all_or_nothing"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "survey_id"
  t.boolean  "date"
  t.boolean  "time"
  t.string   "colors",         default: [], array: true
end
```

Running array.inspect yields:

```
 "[\"7\", \" 8..9\", \" 10\"]"
```

Reading the docs, it's not obvious to me while it's failing. It can't be for a string because it happily passed on the "7" previously. array[1].class => 'String'. My Google searches for this specific situation come up empty. I know it's a Range enclosed in a String, but at this point, it's just a string?

For completeness, it may be helpful to know that I'm using Windows and Ruby 2.0 to build this app.

Where should I look to learn how to resolve this? thanx, sam

Comment: What do you mean by "As you know, each element of an array stored in PG is in strings.", PostgreSQL knows what arrays are and so does AR in Rails4 and you can have arrays of whatever type you want. Where does `array` come from and why is it a string instead of an Array?

Comment: Using rails console, an Item entered in as [4, 5] is returned in as ["4", "5"]. I'm sure you're right but console returns string, as does rails in its views. The array above was entered as you would expect. Not as a string.

Comment: So you've defined the column as a `text[]` or `varchar(n)[]` column, right? Rails would call those `t.text :name, :array => true` or `t.string :name, :array => true`.

Comment: If `array` is `['7', '8..9', '10']` then `array.each_with_index` would work fine so something is going on that you're not telling us.

Comment: schema.rb reports it as string. As with my migration. Should it be something else?

Comment: You are likely right, but I'm unsure what else could be going on. This should be working, even in console.

Comment: Add the appropriate section of your `schema.rb` to the question, the `array.inspect` output might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It must be due to end of a long work day, but after a restart the next day, I cannot reproduce the behavior. It must be said that I've restarted console during this process but apparently I needed to do more to restart the entire environment in Windows. Thanks to mu is too short for hanging with me late to troubleshoot this one-off behavior.